# objective function within tolerance set by ['ACC'] but optimiser continues to run?

Tags: openmdao

Not sure if I understand the ['ACC'] setting within OpenMDAO correctly; I was under the impression that it controls the tolerance for termination. However, if the accuracy of the optimiser is set to 1e-6, then shouldn't the optimiser stop running at iteration 25?

```
 PARAMETERS:
    ACC =   0.1000D-05
    MAXITER =250
    IPRINT =   1
```

IOUT =   6

```
 ITER =   24     OBJ =  0.31020466E-01
 ITER =   25     OBJ =  0.31020193E-01
 ITER =   26     OBJ =  0.31002316E-01
 ITER =   27     OBJ =  0.30993740E-01
```